# The listener stops after a very short silence period

Tags: android, flutter, dart, time, speech-to-text

In the Android app, the user has to say a long sentence, the problem is that if he stops speaking too briefly just to breathe, the listener stops. There is no problem with iOS.

In the documentation of "Android speech recognition" they mentioned how to increase the silence period:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS

But how should i apply it for Flutter?